OpenLayers WebGLPointsLayerRenderer Custom ShaderBuilder Causes Syntax Error in Fragment Shader
I am working on rendering points using OpenLayers' WebGLPointsLayerRenderer with a custom shader defined using the ShaderBuilder utility. My objective is to create a custom WebGL layer with specific rendering effects.
I referred to the OpenLayers documentation and implemented my code based on it. However, when I run the code, I encounter the following error in the browser console:
Uncaught Error: Fragment shader compilation failed: ERROR: 0:1: 'undefined' : syntax error

I also tried using the WebGLPointsLayerRenderer without the ShaderBuilder, but I am still unable to render the points properly.
Code Example
Here is a link to a reproducible example in CodeSandbox:
CodeSandbox Example
The error occurs right at the start of the console log when loading the page.
What I Have Tried

Followed the OpenLayers documentation on ShaderBuilder and WebGLPointsLayerRenderer.
Verified that the ShaderBuilder utility is being used correctly.
Tried using WebGLPointsLayerRenderer directly without custom shaders.

What I Need Help With

Identifying what is causing the syntax error in my fragment shader.
Understanding the correct usage of ShaderBuilder with WebGLPointsLayerRenderer.
Suggestions or examples for rendering points using custom shaders in OpenLayers.

Any guidance or corrections would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Your CodeSandbox Example seems to be not publicly accessible.
